# como realizar una struct de un json que puede devolver un objeto vacio

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3, swift4

Estoy haciendo un llamado a una api que me devuelve el siguiente json, mi problema es que, son varias entradas y de vez en cuando estas pueden aparecer con un objeto vacío, como puedo representarlo en mi estructura para poder decodificarlos correctamente?

```
{
"status": true,
"code": 200,
"message": "Estados",
"body": [
    {
        "codigoEmpresa": "67777777",
        "codigoEquipo": "A_oiL_",
        "Bandera": {},
        "aHorario": {}}]}
```

este es mi struct

```
struct VehicleResponse: Decodable{
let status: Bool
let code: Int
let message: String
let body: [Body]
}
struct Body: Decodable  {
    let codigoEmpresa: String?
    let   codigoEquipo:String?
let Bandera : String
let aHorario: String }
```

aquí estoy teniendo problemas, ya que al ser objeto vacío en ciertos casos, no me permite colocarle un String

Comment: Lo que necesitas es **Optional chaining**, el cual se hace agregando `?` a los variables que pueden ser opcionales. ```
let message: String?
```
[Optional Chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/optionalchaining/)

Comment: Qué te viene vacío `VehicleResponse` o `Body`?. Puedes agregar el error que tienes?